# How to play audio file that i saved to users phone Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

When i clicks the save button an alert pops up that gets the user input for what name they want the file to be saved as.  Then when i hit play button to play the save file it doesnt play it i get "No file"  so my question is how do i get it to play the file that was saved

Code:

```
   @IBAction func saveFinalButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        var saveFileName = ""
        if saveFileName == "" {
            //alert view
            var alertViewControllerTextField: UITextField!

            let promptController = UIAlertController(title: "Type Something", message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
            let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
                saveFileName = alertViewControllerTextField!.text
                //save file
                let fm = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
                let doc = fm.URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true, error: nil)
                let outurl = doc!.URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(saveFileName).aac")
                saveFileURL = saveFileName


                var err : NSError?
                let outfile = AVAudioFile(forWriting: outurl, settings: [
                    AVFormatIDKey : kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC,
                    AVNumberOfChannelsKey : 1,
                    AVSampleRateKey : 22050,
                    AVEncoderBitRatePerChannelKey : 16
                    ], error: &err)

                var done = false
            })
            promptController.addAction(ok)
            promptController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) -> Void in
                alertViewControllerTextField = textField
            }

            presentViewController(promptController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
   }


    @IBAction func playSavedFile(sender: AnyObject) {
        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
        let savedFileTest = documentsPath + "/" + saveFileURL + ".aac"
        let urlSaveFile = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: savedFileTest)

        var error:NSError?

        playSavedFile = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: urlSaveFile, error: &error)
        if (playSavedFile != nil) {
            println("file found")
        } else {
            println("No file")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an impedance mismatch in the way you are forming the name of the file. In one function you are using a URL. In the other function you are using a path string. They are not getting the same result.

It would be much better if you had a single function that they *both* called that generated the same URL.

However, the more serious problem is that you have no code that ever saves the file. You create the URL and the AVAudioFile object, but you never save anything to that file. The way you use an AVAudioFile is with a buffer and the `writeFromBuffer:...` command. You never do that so you get nothing.